# What is the best preamplifier circuit for electret condenser microphone?

Tags: microphone, preamp, distortion

I have one old German directional dynamic microphone "SEL BST 205-1" and I remove everything inside it and pack 2 condenser microphones from mobile phones "Nokia 5130".

Like preamp I use this shematic:
[image]

My problem is that any voice recorded via those microphones sounds like output from a can. I know that these microphones can record better sound and I think my preamp need some tweaks or some special filters.

Comment: You appear to be confusing the word "datasheet" with "schematic" or "circuit".

Comment: Unlikely that a preamp made to work with dynamic microphones and electret microphones will sound good with either.  For starters, you need much more amplification for a dynamic microphone than for an electret.  If the preamp has enough gain for the dynamic, it will have too much when used with the electret.

Comment: Try putting 1 kohm in series with the 100 uF capacitor across R3 to lower the gain and linearize the circuit and reduce distortion.

Comment: Generaly I remove dynamic mycrophone from case and instand of it place electret mycrophones. But my problem is sound quality.

Comment: @Andyaka you mean to repace R3 with 1k ? That can work.

Comment: No, add a 1 k resistor in series with the 100 uF to lower the AC gain.

Comment: @Andyaka Ah yes, you are right.

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić cool profile BTW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a resistor in series with the 100 uF capacitor across R3 as shown below: -

[image]

Without that resistor there is nothing that defines the AC gain of the amplifier and the effect of the 100 uF without the 1 kohm resistor will make the input impedance very low and significantly distort the signal from the microphone.

With the 1 kohm resistor I've added, the circuit AC gain will be around 22 and the input impedance will be around 10 kohm.

Comment: You are totaly right. This is the right answer. Now sound is clear and loder. Is almost perfect but equalizer reduce that. THANKS!

Comment: @Andy aka,
As per the last comment, your suggestion solved the problem. Now, I have a doubt, the circuits working voltage is 6V to 30V. But, R1 is only 1K. Is it a printing mistake.....? In many other circuits I have seen R1 value is 10K. If R1's value printed is wrong, what should be it's value for 9VDC and 12VDC powersupply....?

Comment: R1 is dependent on the electret microphone used and I used the circuit diagram posted by the OP because R1 wasn't the problem here. Indeed much higher values are sometimes used and typically I've seen 3k3 used a few times and 2k2 and 6k8. R1 is chosen for the microphone specifically used. There is no set rule @AnilKumar.K